# Listview filter - filtering on backspace(delete)

Tags: android, listview

I have working `ListView` filtering. This is my needs:

- When i don't have results I displaying empty view.
- When my search is empty - `ListView` get all items.
- When I start typing `ListView` filtering well.

Problem is when I deleting word by word from search I don't have filtering, because I populated my original `ListView` with results. And problems is obvious here. But no idea how to solve it when I delete words my original `ListView` being filtered and displayed.

This is publish result method:

```
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (constraint.length()>0 &&results.count == 0) {
                    _1History =(ArrayList<HistoryModel>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else if(constraint.length()==0){
                    _1History = _1HistoryOriginalData;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    _1History = (ArrayList<HistoryModel>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
```

Comment: When did you called `publishResult` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post is not recent, however it does come up on google searches so I will attempt it.

I assume the problem you are having is that the filter results do not update once you've pressed backspace? I can't really see the root of the problem since only the publishResults method is shown, therefore I will just assume that.

As you begin typing in the search field, the _1History array begins to filter, shortening the size of the array after each character.

```
 _1History =(ArrayList<HistoryModel>) results.values;
```

Meaning each consecutive search query (adding or deleting characters) will search only within the already filtered _1History array.

The issue and its solution is within the performFiltering method. The issue being that you have a loop that searches each item in the _1History array, and removing all objects from that array that do not contain the constraint. The only benefit from that, is that the loop is accessed less times after _1History array is shortened, which could be beneficial performance wise I suppose.

Instead you should search the _1HistoryOriginalData array that contains all of the objects, not just the ones that were recently filtered.

Alternatively if you would like to continue filtering  _1History  and removing objects after each method call in order to minimize the loop. You could add a piece of code at the top of the performFiltering method that checks if a character has been deleted, and only then reset the _1History to have all objects. This might require a global variable. Here is an example of how you might do that:

```
if(previousLength > constraint.length()){
       _1History.clear();
       _1History.addAll(_1HistoryOriginalData);
       previousLength = constraint.length();
}else{
       previousLength = constraint.length();
}
```

previousLength being a global variable.

Comment: nice solution. works for me